# Adding to SendTo Context Menu in Windows 10

Tags: context-menu, windows-10-preview, send-to

OS: Windows 10 Tech Preview Build 10041

I am trying to add shortcuts to the SendTo context menu using the Windows 8 method. Even after adding shortcuts and restarting, the items don't appear in the menu. Have any other Windows 10 users had problems with this?

Comment: Have you tried an earlier build?  The method to add something to the context menu has not changed since Windows XP was released.

Comment: CHeck the list of entries in the sendto folder and if one of them is zero bytes in size delete it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Make a shortcut of your folder on the desktop
2. Open the run window - WIN+R
3. Type **shell:sendto** into the run box. Then OK. That opens the sendto folder.
4. Drag your shortcut from the desktop into the sendto folder. Close the folder.

I just tested that on build 10061

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing. Oh well, probably an issue with just my computer. I will try updating to the most recent build.

Comment: Maybe you mad a typo - e.g. with the colon. Unfortunately I do not have build 10041 any more. But I just tested it on a backup copy of build 10049 and there it worked too. I suggest you try it again. It is a basic staple of Windows and should work.

Comment: Ok, I eventually got it working. My original shortcut was to an executable jar file. That wasn't working, so I had to create a shortcut to a batch file, and from there I started the jar file.
Anyways, thanks for the helpful comments.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad you got it to work.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to pass parameters through a batch file, but I guess that's a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Clicking the Start button and start typing `shell:sendto` right away doesn't work anymore (as it did in Windows 7). In Windows 10 you have to start a Run dialog first and type it there.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with some shortcuts. If your shortcuts are not appearing, check their properties. Chances are it's a weird non-standard shortcut. I had this issue with Notepad and Visual Studio Code shortcuts. Re-create a shortcut from scratch that points directly to the folder or EXE or whatever and you're good to go.

Comment: The shortcut  "target" should look like `%windir%\system32\notepad.exe` not the GUID\notepad thing and "TargetType" of "Application" not some GUID - so dragging it off the Windows 10 Windows/Accessories does not work for instance